# Integer compare operations using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?-->

<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>11.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1994</YEAR>
  </CD>-----so on
```

I'm trying to search this xml doc using another xml which is like

```
<search_conditions>
    <condition>
        <price min="20" max="45"/>
    </condition>
</search_conditions>
```

This is my code that i wrote:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="query1"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="query1">
        <xsl:variable name="minPrice" select="document('search.xml')/search_conditions/condition/price/@min" />
        <xsl:variable name="maxPrice" select="document('search.xml')/search_conditions/condition/price/@max" />

        <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="//CD">

            <xsl:if test="PRICE &gt; $minPrice" >
                <xsl:if test="PRICE &lt; $maxPrice" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ARTIST" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="COMPANY" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="YEAR" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

but when im trying to run this thing, nothing is printing out. Why? what am i doing wrong here? Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions to be used are these:

```
<xsl:variable name="minPrice" select="document('search.xml')/search_conditions/condition/price/@min" />
<xsl:variable name="maxPrice"  select="document('search.xml')/search_conditions/condition/price/@max" />
```

Comment: yep i have 4 values in between 20 and 45 but still not printing anything

Comment: It should.. it does :)

Comment: if the path to the search.xml is right, and if you are using one of the "PARAM" like <PARAM>21.0</PARAM>.. I think you shouldn't face any problem

Comment: search.xml is in the same folder as that of cdcatalog.xml. I have been working on it since last night cant seem to figure out why it is not printing

Comment: just to ensure, the search.xml should be in the same directory as the XSLT file..

Comment: Yes, they all are in same folder

Comment: if you could see if all the three files are valid XMLs? like by opening all in browsers

Comment: Your code is working as @LingamurthyCS says. I just tested it using Saxon 6, Saxon 9 and Xalan. If there is still a problem, it's probably  related to your environment.

Comment: Since you are comparing values, it can also fail because of encoding or some other reason. Try creating a new file, with just a few CDs and see if it works. Try to answer your own question as we did (cut and paste the code from this page into new files.)